# Proving distributive nature dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In my physics textbook on the chapter vectors it asks me to prove that $$\mathbf {a \cdot (b+c)} = \mathbf {a \cdot b+ a \cdot c} .$$ So I thought to prove it as follows:

*Since* $$\mathbf {x \cdot y} =xy \cos \theta$$ ($\theta$ being the angle between the two vectors)

*Therefore* $$\mathbf {a \cdot (b+c)} = a(| \mathbf {b+c}|) \cos \theta$$

Now I can't go any further. Can somebody tell me if its possible to prove that through the above stated method? If so how?

---

**EDIT**
I know how to do it the way [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3428141/690654) did it but I'm just wondering whether the way I'm trying to prove it is possible to do(if so how?), even if it's hardest way to do it!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215063/prove-the-distributive-property-of-the-dot-product-using-its-geometric-definitio) will help.

Comment: are you looking for a proof in three dimensions using the geometric interpretation?

Comment: I guess you should try doing something like [this one](https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2Fb36%2Fb3624d3f-a4d4-449c-b74d-5e7d4de2393f%2Fimage.png).

Comment: @A. $\Gamma$. Thanks that really helped. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overthinking it: $$a\cdot(b+c)=\sum_ia_i(b+c)_i=\sum_ia_i(b_i+c_i)=\sum_ia_ib_i+\sum_ia_ic_i=a\cdot b+a\cdot c.$$

Comment: @Ramanujan_π The issue is you know one of two equivalent definitions. For this problem, you need to understand why they're equivalent. (Any good textbook treatment, be it in mathematics or physics, will help.) It's all explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition).

Answer (score 0):

Let

- $\vec a=a_x \hat i+a_y \hat j$
- $\vec b=b_x \hat i+b_y \hat j$
- $\vec c=c_x \hat i+c_y \hat j$

then since $\hat i\cdot \hat i=1$, $\hat j\cdot \hat j=1$, $\hat i\cdot \hat j=0$

$$\vec a\cdot(\vec b+\vec c)=(a_x \hat i+a_y \hat j)[(b_x+c_x)\hat i+(b_y+c_y)\hat j]=(a_xb_x+a_xc_x)+(a_yb_y+a_yc_y)=$$

$$=(a_xb_x+a_yb_y )+(a_xc_x+a_yc_y )=\vec a \cdot \vec b+\vec a \cdot \vec c$$

The result can be extended in a similar way for vectors in $\mathbb R^3$.